# Fetch Protected API with protected access token in Pimcore

Tags: pimcore, data-importer, pimcore-datahub

How i can make consume Protected API in pimcore through Data Importer. There is no input tab in pimcore to enter Access Token Key. Is there any other possible ways to do it?

[This is our api which I am trying to load into pimcore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKuh.jpg)